# Problem in understanding the last part of Theorem $7.7$ in Kirillov.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

I am  trying to prove the fourth and the last part of **Theorem 7.7** from the first three parts. If $y \in \mathfrak g_{-\alpha}$ then by $(3)$ we have for all $\gamma \neq \alpha$ $$K \left (\mathfrak g_{-\alpha}, \mathfrak g_{\gamma}  \right ) = (0).$$ Hence for all $x \in \bigoplus\limits_{\gamma \neq \alpha} \mathfrak g_{\gamma}$ we have $K (x,y) = 0.$ If we can show that $K (x,y) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ then we are through by $(1)$ and the nondegeneracy of the Killing form. But I can't conclude that. Could anyone help me out here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that the restriction wasn't nondegenerate for some $\alpha$.  Then (swapping $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ if necessary), we can find a non-zero $x\in \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ such that $K(x,\mathfrak g_{-\alpha})=0$.  But by (3), $K(x,\mathfrak g_{\beta})=0$ for all $\beta \neq -\alpha$, and since $\mathfrak g$ is a direct sum of the subspaces, this shows that $K(x,\mathfrak g)=0$, and so $K$ is degenerate, which we know to be false.

Comment: My question is why does the killing form give us the nondegenerate pairing $\mathfrak g_{\alpha} \otimes \mathfrak g_{-\alpha} \longrightarrow \mathbb C\ $? I haven't asked about any restriction. Please go through my question again carefully.

Comment: And this answered that. We have to use the orthogonality of the weight spaces together with non-degeneracy on the whole Lie algebra.

Comment: Assuming you are missing a negative sign, that is essentially the definition of what it means for the pairing to be degenerate.

Comment: To be clear, the pairing $\mathfrak g_{\alpha}\otimes \mathfrak g_{-\alpha}\to \mathbb C$ is the restriction of the Killing form to a subspace of $\mathfrak g_{\alpha}\otimes \mathfrak g_{-\alpha}\subset \mathfrak g \otimes \mathfrak g$.